How to find $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} (-\frac{1}{2})^n$?
I received this problem as homework recently and had no idea where to begin. I asked WolframAlpha, and it said that the answer is $ln(1.5)$. This didn't really help my understanding, though, so I asked about the more general $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$. It yielded the formula $-ln(1 - x)$, but I have no idea how it got there. Can someone help me understand how to get these results?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
